# Suppress SQL*PLUS error in batch script

Tags: sql, windows, oracle, batch-file

I have a script **db.bat** as below:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (user.txt) do (
    sqlplus -s %%A @fetch.sql  >> output.txt 

 )
```

where **user.txt** (list of all user details for which I need expiry date. this list may have around 40-50 rows) is:

```
dbuser/password@database1
readuser/p@ssw0rd@database1
adminuser/Pa$$word@database2
.......
.......
.......
```

and **fetch.sql** is:

```
set pagesize 20
set linesize 200

select username, expiry_date from user_users;
exit;
```

The problem I am facing here is, whenevey my script db.bat encounters any SQL ERRORS like given below, its not moving further and getting hanged at that point until I manually stop that.

**SQL ERRORs**:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked
```

I have checked that there is a WHENEVER SQLERROR command that works in this situation but don't know how I can use it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those kinds of errors, SQL*Plus is 'hanging' at a username prompt, as it hasn't been able to connect. You don't see that because of the `-s` flag. By default it will allow three attempts, which is useful when running interactively, but isn't helpful when run from a script like this. You can make it exit after the failed login with [the `-l` 'logon' option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169374):

```
sqlplus -s -l %%A @fetch.sql  >> output.txt
```

Comment: ...I just observed that its getting hanged on ERROR: ORA-28001: the password has expired Changing password for USERNAME...despite using -l flag :-( any suggestion please ? :-)

Comment: @Sunny - sorry, missed this comment notification; it's probably useful as a separate question/answer anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, when using the fetch.sql in a script, you need to set the termout to off.
The error is still there, only that your script will continue to execute after it.

```
set pagesize 20
set linesize 200

whenever sqlerror continue 
set termout off 

select username, expiry_date from user_users;
exit;
```

Comment: If  I am doing like this then there is only Error messages are recorded in output.txt.