# Handle db connection errors batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus

I have the following code:

```
sqlplus web/%password%@%SID% @ web.sql > weblog.log < NUL

if %ERRORLEVEL% > 0 GOTO SQLERROR

:SQLERROR

echo wrong credentials
```

The problem is, when I give wrong SID or password it pauses for some seconds and does not go to the error. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: It only pauses for a few seconds, it doesn't hang indefinitely - or at least until you hit return a few times, or interrupt it? [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27945425/266304) - does adding the `-l` flag make it behave how you want it to?.

Comment: It pauses for some secs, it does not respond to whatever i type except ctrl+c, the error is logged in weblog though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% gtr 0 GOTO SQLERROR
```

`>` is a redirector. You must use one of `==`, `gtr`, `geq`, `equ`, `neq`, `'lss`, 'leq`in an`if` statement.

Comment: Thank you. The delay was caused because of the 3 attempts to connect to the database.